# Strict Equality in JQuery '$' selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a custom data attribute in the  element that are rendered in the html

```
<div my-custom-attrib="1".../>
<div my-custom-sttrib="2".../>
```

Now in the JQuery I want to filter between the  elements based on the custom attribute value
for that I'm doing the JQuery code like this:

```
var value = GetValueOfCustomAttribWeDontNeed() //-> This function returns an Int Value
$('[my-custom-attrib !="'+value+'"]').foreach(...)
```

Here when I'm using this '!=' (or '==') then its working perfectly,
but when i'm trying to use strict equality ('===' or '!=='), its throwing error saying the expression is unrecognized.

```
$('[my-custom-attrib!=="'+value+'"]').foreach(...)
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [my-custom-attrib!=="2"]]
```

My question is: is it even possible to use strict equality in '$' selector like this or there is any other way, or can we only use normal equality operators in '$' selector?

Comment: jQuery selectors don't use strict equality checks. It's only ever `==` or `!=`. This is because attributes are always read and compared as strings. If you want to enforce data types, use `filter()` and supply your own comparison logic.

Comment: For more information see the selector docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it. Selector you use is CSS selector and its syntax for attribute selectors `!=` has nothing to do with Javascript comparison operators. If you want to be able to use Javscript, you will need to select all elements with attribute `[my-custom-attrib]` and then filter necessary elements:

```
$('[my-custom-attrib]').filter(function () {
  return $(this).attr('my-custom-attrib') !== value
}).each(function () {
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery selectors is based on CSS selectors. jQuery add some new pseudo selectors (like `:input`) but it's still CSS syntax.

CSS attribute selectors does not support strict equality because in the CSS world everything is a string.

[More information on CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)